# Creating a download link in a new page once a form is submited html

Tags: javascript, html, forms, perl, download

I have an HTML form that saves the information entered and puts it in an Excel file on the server. I want to make this file available for download once the form is submitted.

My current download button is

```
<a href="data.xlsx">Download data</a>
```

My form links to a Perl script that processes the data. However once the form is processed it goes to a new page. I would like the new page to either display an error message or a link to download the file. I am unsure how to link to a new page because my form is already linked to the perl script.

I'm not very familiar with HTML or JavaScript, so if anyone has a simple idea for me that would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the Perl program redirect to another page, or does it output the page? It seems you misunderstand what linking means. Your form gets submitted to the Perl program. That doesn't mean it can't send the user back. However, a single html document usually doesn't handle incoming data very well. Please show us how your form looks like, be more specific about what kind of page it is in, and show the part of the Perl script that happens after processing the upload is done. Also, do you want it available for download for the same user or for other users later?

Answer (score -4):

You can try jQuery and append your link like this:

```
$('body').append('<a href\'data.xls\'>Download Link</a>');
```

Comment: The op says that they control the server side application that creates the document. There is no need to do anything client side.